# LWJGL: glMapBuffer/Range what is the use of old buffer?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

```
//length > 0 for all cases
ByteBuffer oldBuffer=BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(length);
ByteBuffer newBuffer=GL30.glMapBufferRange(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,length,GL30.GL_MAP_READ_BIT ,oldBuffer);
   
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){System.out.println(oldBuffer.get(i));}
System.out.println();
```

It prints out all zero's but the new buffer contains the correct data which is fine.
And if i specify null as parameter for the old buffer it works fine too.

So is there any optimization/memory saving being done behind the scenes when using an non null old buffer? The output is the same for LWJGL 2.9.3 and 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an LWJGL-specific optimization. It is intended to avoid having to allocate a new NIO Buffer object pointing to the mapped address in case when OpenGL returns the same address that was previously returned as a NIO Buffer, that you now provide as `old_buffer`.

See also in the LWJGL 3 sources of [GL15C.glMapBuffer()](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/6e5b2ba3bdacaebd97052b1680f2c1536e0250a5/modules/lwjgl/opengl/src/generated/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL15C.java#L653) as well as the called [APIUtil.apiGetMappedBuffer()](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/6e5b2ba3bdacaebd97052b1680f2c1536e0250a5/modules/lwjgl/core/src/main/java/org/lwjgl/system/APIUtil.java#L158).

However, when the OpenGL driver decides to map the buffer memory to another virtual address, then you still will get a new/fresh NIO Buffer instance.

Comment: So should i make my own bytebuffer and use that as the oldBuffer parameter or should i use the byteBuffer returns by the glMapBuffer[assuming it was given special memory] or will it not make an diffrence?

Comment: Also will it write[if/when it does] into the same position as i have specified in that buffer or will the buffer positions be changed when it does write?

Comment: I see. So i should use ByteBuffer returned by the glMapBuffer as it contains glMapped memory is what you are saying? but if LWJGL can make this optimization why dosen't the original glMapBuffer in opengl have no such optimization?

Comment: That make's sense since C works with pointers. So for performance purposes i should store the returned ByteBuffer as an global variable and reuse that something like oldBuffer=glMapBuffer(...,oldBuffer) correct?

Comment: But LWJGL dosen't have an persistent flag as one of the the [GL_MAP flags](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL30.html#GL_MAP_FLUSH_EXPLICIT_BIT). how do i create an persistent buffer?

Comment: I'm so sorry . Anyway you have perfectly answered my question ,unfortunately persistent buffers happens to be another gl 4.4 feature so I guess i will stick to reusing whatever buffer was returned by the mapBufferRange. Thank you :)